# Symfony 3.3 pre-fill custom form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a custom form in Symfony 3.3 with the following information:

```
                $builder->add('frecuency', TextType::class, array('required' => false,
        'label' => 'Execution Frecuency: '))
                    ->add('save_submit', SubmitType::class, 
                            array('label' => 'Save'));
```

I do not need anymore fields on this form, but the information of this comes from the following entity that has more fields:

```
/**
(...)
class SrvrsServers
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;
(...)
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="frequency", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */    
private $frequency;
```

Then my problem is how to fill this field `frecuency` from the DB if the form is totally customised as compared to the DB entoty.

My controller for now looks something like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/server/{id}", name="edit_server")
 */
public function editAction ($id){

    $server = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NCbrtBundle:SrvrsServers')
            ->find($id);
    if (!$server) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Server not found for ID:  '. $id);
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(ServerType::class);

    return $this->render('NCbrtBundle:Server:server.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'server' => $server,
    ));
}
```

I do not know how or where to get this information to the form and how to write it. There is another problem, I need to filter the information coming from the DB and add or modify it depending on the value. This field is stored in seconds and I need to store it in a human readable format like minutes, hours or days. I already have functions (a class) to do that, but can not use it so far. Can someone help a bit here?

As additional information this is how the form looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data Transformer to translate the data for a field into a format that can be displayed in a form (and back on submit).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    //...
    $builder->add('frecuency', TextType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'label' => 'Execution Frecuency: ')
    )
    //...

    $builder->get('frecuency')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($hashToReadableString) {
                // make readable string from hash
                $readableString = MyLib::unHash($hashToReadableString);

                return $readableString;
            },
            function ($readableStringToHash) {
                // transform the readable string back to a hash string
                $hashString = MyLib::hash($readableStringToHash);

                return $hashString;
            }
        ))
    ;
}
```

The CallbackTransformer takes two callback functions as arguments. The first transforms the original value into a format that'll be used to render the field. The second does the reverse: it transforms the submitted value back into the format you'll use in your code.

source : [Data Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: This does not fully answer the question, but was very useful I have to recognize.